# Why is Fei able to fly when she's an earth dragon?

Tags: so-im-a-spider-so-what

Earth dragons are specifically mentioned to have no wings and be unable to fly, so how is Fei able to do so?

From when Araba first shows up:

> Contrary to it's name, it looked more like a wolf.
>
> It had four feet that trod on the ground.
>
> A long tail.
>
> No wings.
>
> What I saw there was an imposingly majestic dragon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not have been explained adequately in the anime (or perhaps I just have a knack for not paying attention). Firstly, note that Fei was an earth wyrm, not an earth dragon, and this series makes a distinction between these, as a dragon is a more evolved form (which Fei may reach someday). Now, for the answer.

Fei is able to fly because she evolves into a light wyrm. This is a special evolution that becomes available to her because she's the hero's familiar. From the light novels, volume 3, chapter S6: *Hiding*:

> Fei had evolved, becoming a light wyrm.
>
> Apparently, this new evolution was suddenly available to her because I became the hero.
>
> Since we have a contract as master and familiar, my obtaining the Hero title had an indirect effect on Fei
>
> According to Hyrince, there have been similar cases in the past.
>
> When a hero has a monster familiar, that monster undergoes a a special evolution.
>
> This is how Fei apparently shifted gears from being an earth wyrm to a light wyrm.
>
> With her powers as an earth wyrm still intact.
>
> Earth wyrms are known for their exceptional defense power.
>
> So Fei gets to keep that defense, while gaining the ability to maneuver freely on both land and sky thanks to her new wings.
>
> Her newly acquired skills are Light Wyrm level 9, Light Magic level 1, and Flight level 1.

Though Shun doesn't notice at first, he also figures out Fei has a hard time flying straight since her Flight is still level 1, after he tells her to fly straight at an enemy:

> I couldn't tell up until now, but it seems like Fei really isn't used to flying yet, since she hasn't trained the skill up at all.
>
> Apparently, flying straight is even more difficult than dodging the beam attacks.